# rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got stuck on production environment for rails application because my assets are not compiled. When I use

`rvmsudo bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace`

It throws `rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding"`

Here is my Gemfile:

```
            source 'https://rubygems.org'
            gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
            gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
            gem 'jquery-rails'
            gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
            gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
            gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
            gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
            gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
            gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
            gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
            gem 'haml'
            gem 'haml-rails'
            gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'
            gem 'html2haml'
            gem 'simple_form'
            gem 'validates_formatting_of'
            gem 'tzinfo-data'
            gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
            gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
            gem 'jquery-validation-rails'
            gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
            gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

            gem 'paperclip'
            gem 'fancybox-rails'
            gem 'css3-progress-bar-rails'

            group :development do
              gem 'spring'
              gem 'pry-rails'
              gem 'better_errors'
            end

            group :development, :test do
              gem 'rspec-rails'
              gem 'factory_girl_rails'
            end

            gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

            # Need daemons to start delayed_job
            gem 'daemons'

            gem 'rails_config', '~> 0.4.2'
            gem 'cancan'
            gem 'two_factor_authentication'
            gem 'twilio-ruby'
            gem 'binding_of_caller'
            gem 'rest-client'
```

Here is my porduction.rb

```
  Rails.application.configure do
      config.cache_classes = true
      config.eager_load = true
      config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
      config.serve_static_files = true
      config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
      config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
      config.assets.compile = false
      config.assets.compress = false
      config.assets.digest = true
      config.log_level = :debug

      config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
      config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
      config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
      config.i18n.fallbacks = true
      config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
      config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => Settings.PROD_URL }
      config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
      config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
    end
```

And application.css:

```
    /*
    *= require_tree .
    *= require_self
    */
```

So, why i am getting `rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding"` while compiling.
My production works but no css is loaded to it.

Comment: Check where you have used the variable `$alert-padding` and define it prior to using it at that place.

Comment: Does the error message say where the error happens? Filename or line?

Comment: At a line: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_alerts.scss:10`. Because `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss` is not loaded before _alerts. Therefore it throws an error for `undefined symbol for $alert-padding`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 2):

`$alert-padding` variable is used before being defined. It may be caused by a wrong order of css files in `application.css`. `require_tree` loads all files from the current folder in alphabetical order (I guess), but you need some styles to loaded in specific order.

It seems like you're using `bootstrap-sass` gem. Consider the following instruction from the gem's README: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails You need to rename `application.css` to `application.scss` and use `@import` instead of `require`.

Comment: I had renamed all css files to scss. And removed the require and imported all scss files in application.scss file.
But still the same error persists.

Comment: Did you keep the order? `bootstrap-sprockets` must be imported before `bootstrap`.

Comment: Yes. I have done the same. But it again throws an error.

Comment: Yes, the sequence seems to be right. Variables are included inside `bootstrap`.

Try to remove importing of `bootstrap.min` and `bootstrap_and_overrides`. You don't need them, because you already have `bootstrap-sass`.

You can also try to clear `application.scss`, add each `@import` one by one and recompile assets. At some point you'll see which style produces the error. This style should be imported after `@import "bootstrap"`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add these lines in your config/application.rb if you are using scss instead of css.

```
config.assets.precompile << %w( *.scss *.js )
```

Answer (score 1):

With `SASS` you have to include your variables *before* they're called.

Dir globbing / [Sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#index-files-are-proxies-for-folders) include files *alphabetically*:

> This has the problem that files are required alphabetically. If your directory has jquery-ui.js and jquery.min.js then Sprockets will require jquery-ui.js before jquery is required which won't work (because jquery-ui depends on jquery).

This means if you're using a `variables.sass` (or similar), you'll want to either rename it, or include it explicitly:

```
/*
   *= require variables
   *= require_tree .
   *= require_self
   *= stub variables
*/
```

Even better (since you're using `SASS`), use the `@import` directive:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass
@import variables
@import *
```

Comment: I don't have any custom variables file. But I need `bootstrap/variables` should be compiled before the scss partials.  
I tried to import `@import 'bootstrap/variables'`
But show `Unable to import this file of text/css`

Comment: Is that the actual error (`unable to import this file of text/css`)?

Comment: I moved _variables.scss from bootstrap gem folder to stylesheets and renamed this file as variables and imported it to application.scss
But the another issue is i set  `config.assets.precompile +=  ['*.js','*.css','*.png','*.jpg','*.woff','*.ttf']` in production.rb. So here while precompiling, the files are compiled alphabetically. 
But when i commented this and compiled then only application.scss is ccompiled. But the CSS inside the another files are not loaded. Am i still missing something ?

Comment: They would compile separately if  you didn't `@import` them - can you show me all the `@imports` you're calling for your CSS

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue
I just added this two lines in environment/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile += %w( active_admin.css.scss )
```

It works for me.