# compiling with the variables in _vars.scss ruby on rails 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

it's my first time to compiling a ruby on rails 2.0, and I have a problem with the variables in `_vars.scss`. The scss files are located in `vendor/assets/stylesheets/scss` (I located them here because was the only way they worked!) and they are calling them up in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`:

```
@import "scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "scss/vars.scss";
@import "scss/styles.scss";
@import "scss/fonts.scss";
@import "scss/icons.scss";
@import "scss/helpers.scss";
```

The problem that showed up is:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$screen-sm-max".


(in /var/rails/DeterminaRASIntegracio/releases/20180414113247/vendor/assets/stylesheets/scss/_styles.scss)
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa I don't know what to do! what can I do to make this work? I read bunch of posts I can't find any solution.

Comment: Use the `.scss` extension. The `.css.scss` extension was depreachiated quite a while back. https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/643

Comment: @max but is ruby on rails 2.0, should I changed to .scss anyway?

Comment: Does Rails 2.0 even have an assets pipeline? I thought it was introduced in 3.1.

Comment: Always put your Vars file first in the import list. Or make sure "$screen-sm-max" is ina  file imported before its use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$alert-padding"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504913/rake-aborted-sasssyntaxerror-undefined-variable-alert-padding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear.
Sass tried to find variable `$screen-sm-max` on file _styles.scss but failed.

Try to add

`$screen-sm-max: 42;`

on file _styles.scss.

And see if that solves the problem.